# Programmatically detect 'packed B-frames' AVI files

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a set of old AVI files that I wish to fix using ffmpeg 'mpeg4_unpack_bframes' filter.

I can manually detect them, simply running `ffplay` and I'll get a clear message:

```
[mpeg4 @ 0x55ef7bd90980] Video uses a non-standard and wasteful way to store B-frames ('packed B-frames'). Consider using the mpeg4_unpack_bframes bitstream filter without encoding but stream copy to fix it.
```

Then it is easy to fix using:

```
$ ffmpeg -i packed_bframes.avi -codec copy -bsf:v mpeg4_unpack_bframes unpacked_bframes.avi
```

My question is: what command line tool can I use on GNU/Linux (eg. Debian) to detect those files and only those (possibly without DISPLAY) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, the best I could find is:

```
$ ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -v info -i packed_bframes.avi -ss 0 -t 1 -an -c:v mpeg4 -f null /dev/null 2>&1 | grep mpeg4_unpack_bframes
[mpeg4 @ 0x559262225100] Video uses a non-standard and wasteful way to store B-frames ('packed B-frames'). Consider using the mpeg4_unpack_bframes bitstream filter without encoding but stream copy to fix it.
```

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to avoid [grepping ffmpeg's warnings from stdout/stderr](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/32697/40480) in my own tools, so I looked for an alternative/stabler approach. The key to how ffmpeg detects packed B-frames is here:

1. https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/f4b4e16641184b2414e5822c49fa5f6f9a57f2fb/libavcodec/mpeg4videodec.c#L2949
2. https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/f4b4e16641184b2414e5822c49fa5f6f9a57f2fb/libavcodec/mpeg4videodec.c#L3677

Unfortunately, `ffprobe` does not inform on the existence of packed B-frames and depending on your needs, implementing/linking an entire MPEG4 stream decoder might be overkill.

Fortunately you can use `ffprobe` and little code to programmatically detect them:

```sh
ffprobe -show_packets -select_streams v -read_intervals '%+#1' -show_entries packet=size,pos path/to/file.avi
```

Then open the AVI file, seek `pos`, read `size` bytes and Regex-search for `\x00\x00\x01\xB2DivX(\d+)b(\d+)p` or `\x00\x00\x01\xB2DivX(\d+)Build(\d+)p`. Here `\x00\x00\x01\xB2` stands for the MPEG4 "User data" magic sequence.

You can see an example here: https://github.com/AlexAltea/curator/commit/f9b06146fde30dce0a422ca05a6ed7fa675da6ad

This should always correctly identify packed B-frames: when reformatting with `-bsf:v mpeg4_unpack_bframes` (or equivalent options in other tools), the `p` flag at the end of the DivX identifier gets removed.

If you ever come across false postives (unpacked videos that still have the `p` flag), you can further improve by querying `ffprobe -show_frames`. I've noticed that packed B-frames always get reported as having `pkt_size == 8`.